Getting error while using Job Posting API '/v2/simpleJobPostings' : Not enough permissions to access: simpleJobPostings.BATCH_CREATE.NO_VERSION
I'm working on integrating LinkedIn's API for posting jobs, and I'm encountering an issue with the '/v2/simpleJobPostings' endpoint. I have the following setup :

Client ID and Client Secret have been generated.

I've added the following products to my app:

'Share on LinkedIn'

'Advertising API'

'Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect'



I'm using OAuth 2.0 with the "Member authorization code (3-legged)" flow.

The token has the following permissions :


email, openid, profile, r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile,
r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin,
w_member_social, w_organization_social


I'm making a POST request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/simpleJobPostings with the following payload:

{
 "elements": [{
   "integrationContext": "urn:li:organization:104629273",
   "companyApplyUrl": "http://linkedin.com",
   "description": "We are looking for a passionate Software Engineer...",
   "employmentStatus": "PART_TIME",
   "externalJobPostingId": "1234",
   "listedAt": 1440716666,
   "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
   "title": "Software Engineer",
   "location": "India",
   "workplaceTypes": ["remote"]
  },
  {
   "integrationContext": "urn:li:organization:104629273",
   "companyApplyUrl": "http://linkedin.com",
   "description": "We are looking for a passionate Software Engineer...",
   "employmentStatus": "PART_TIME",
   "externalJobPostingId": "1234",
   "listedAt": 1440716666,
   "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
   "title": "Software Engineer",
   "location": "San Francisco, CA",
   "workplaceTypes": ["hybrid"]
  },
  {
   "integrationContext": "urn:li:organization:104629273",
   "companyApplyUrl": "http://linkedin.com",
   "description": "We are looking for a passionate Senior Software Engineer...",
   "employmentStatus": "PART_TIME",
   "externalJobPostingId": "789",
   "listedAt": 1440716666,
   "jobPostingOperationType": "CREATE",
   "title": "Senior Software Engineer",
   "location": "San Francisco, CA"
  }
 ]
}


The request is authenticated using a Bearer Token generated via OAuth 2.0.

Problem: When I send this request using Postman, I receive the following error response:
{
    "status": 403,
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: simpleJobPostings.BATCH_CREATE.NO_VERSION"
}

Despite adding the 'Advertising API' product and regenerating the token with the additional permissions, I'm still getting the same "ACCESS_DENIED" error.

What could be the reason for this error, and how can I resolve it?

Is there a specific permission or product that I need to enable to use the simpleJobPostings endpoint?


